# How to remove duplicate element in list?

Tags: python, string, list

The assignment says: Write a Python program that reads in a sentence. The program converts the string (that the user input) to a list and prints the sentence as a list of string objects. The program then uses a loop to remove any punctuation (that appears on the punctuation list) from the list. Finally, the program converts the list to a string and prints the sentence without the punctuations. The following punctuation list needs to be copied into your program:

punctuation = ['(', ')', '?', ':', ';', ',', '.', '!', '/', '"', "'", " "]

NOTE: Use the join method in the str class to convert the list to a string.

So I've basically got it all down, this is my code:

```
#punctuation list
punctuation = ['(', ')', '?', ':', ';', ',', '.', '!', '/', '"', "'", " "]

#make an empty list for string to list
converted_list = []
import copy
#tell user to input a sentence
sentence = str(input("Type in a line of text: "))

#Convert str to list
for char in sentence:
    converted_list.append(char)
    newlist = copy.deepcopy(converted_list)
    #remove punctuation from this list
    for character in newlist:
        if (character in punctuation):
            newlist.remove(character)
            newline = "".join(newlist)


print(converted_list)
print(newline)
```

But the problem is, my output shows:

```
Type in a line of text: Hey! Where are you?
['H', 'e', 'y', '!', ' ', 'W', 'h', 'e', 'r', 'e', ' ', 'a', 'r', 'e', ' ', 'y', 'o', 'u', '?']
HeyWhereare you
```

It's only removing the first "space" character. How would I remove the second "space" after 'are'?

Comment: Is your indentation correct? It seems like everything from `newlist = ...` should be unindented to me.

Comment: it still gives me the same input :/

Comment: Ever heard of re-python-library for regex? Especially the re.replace() method?

Answer (score 0):

Try to keep it as simple as possible:

```
#punctuation list
punctuation = ['(', ')', '?', ':', ';', ',', '.', '!', '/', '"', "'", " "]

#make an empty list for string to list
converted_list = []
#tell user to input a sentence
sentence = str(input("Type in a line of text: "))

#Convert str to list
for char in sentence:
    if char not in punctuation:
        converted_list.append(char)

print(converted_list)
print("".join(converted_list))
```

Output will be:

```
Type in a line of text: "Hey! Where are you?"
['H', 'e', 'y', 'W', 'h', 'e', 'r', 'e', 'a', 'r', 'e', 'y', 'o', 'u']
HeyWhereareyou
```

Comment: omg thank you so much! yes, this seems much cleaner and much simpler to read

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
sentence = str(input("Type in a line of text: ")
punctuation = ['(', ')', '?', ':', ';', ',', '.', '!', '/', '"', "'", " "]
converted_list = [char for char in sentence if char not in punctuation]
print(converted_list)
```

Answer (score -3):

For removing spaces in a string we can use nospace keyword.
Eg:

str1 = "TH ABC 123"

str1sp = nospace(srt1)

print(str1sp)

ANS:

THABC123

Comment: There is no `nospace` in Python.